# Tensorflow 2.0 Object Detection API Model Zoo

Tags: api, tensorflow, object, detection

With official support for Tensorflow 2.0, the Object Detection API has also released a new model zoo.

The Tensorflow 1.X model zoo explicitly stated that "timings were performed using an Nvidia GeForce GTX TITAN X" but the new model zoo (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) makes no such statement.

Is it safe to assume the same hardware was used for benchmarking or are these timings only relative timings for the other 2.0 models?

Answer (score 0):

In [tf2_training_and_evaluation document](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_training_and_evaluation.md#training-with-multiple-gpus), I found a configuration with nvidia-tesla-v100.
Therefore,they might have used nvidia-tesla-v100 gpu